# Move object along it's normal axis

Tags: objects, transforms

I am following a tutorial and I have an issue moving an object along it's normal axis, the one perpendicular to it's face. I tried Global and Normal gizmo and it didn't work.
I am stuck.

How can I solve this issue?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to edit mode and select one face.
Press add button
[image]

exit edit mode and move it.
[image]